# What will be the solution to the $n$ dimensional ODE of the form

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

I am trying to figure out but am unable to. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

What will be the solution to the $n$ dimensional ODE of the form

$$dX_i(t)= \sum_{j=1}^nf_{ij}(t)X_j(t) $$
with $X_i(0)=1, i=1, \cdots,n$.
Here $X=(X_1,\cdots,  X_{n})$ where $X_i$ is one dimensional for every $i$. $f=(f_1, \cdots,f_n)$ with $f_{ij}:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+\cup\{0\}$ for every $i,j$.

Comment: You can do the special case when the matrices whose entries are $f_{ij}(t)$ all commute with one another. Then the solution is $X(t)=\exp \left ( \int_0^t A(s) ds \right ) X(0)$. Otherwise it's not an analytically tractable problem as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Can we then simulate it by Euler scheme or some other method. if yes, do you have some thoughts as to how that can be done? Any hints or references for that?

Comment: Sure, just about any ODE integrator should be fine unless some of the $f_{ij}$ have singularities.

Comment: @Ian Can you please elaborate on that. Thanks :)

Comment: What's there to say? Do you know anything about, say, Matlab solvers like ode45 etc.?

Comment: Actually not. I have been mostly towards finance, math finance. I haven't seen this or even ode's for a while.  I happen to see this equation and don't know how one can get its solution. I was not thinking of simulating this. So basically I was looking for a solution and if not then develop a schema to approximate the same theoretically.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, that can't usually be solved in closed form, though the commutation property that I mentioned has a decent chance to hold in a real world problem. You can type, say, "help ode45" in Matlab or (I think) Octave to learn how to use it. It may break in your particular case, in which case there are many other solvers. I personally use ode15s extensively in my own work.